# Scala: retrieve type parameter from generic collection (ClassTag?)

Tags: scala, generics, types, type-inference

I am defining an abstract class taking a type parameter, along with several concrete classes which set this type.

```
abstract class GenericFoo[T: ClassTag] {
    def defaultValue: T
    def useTheValue(v: T): T
}
object DoubleFoo extends GenericFoo[Double] {
    def defaultValue = 42.0
    def useTheValue(v: Double) = v * 2
}
object IntFoo extends GenericFoo[Int] {
    def defaultValue = 1337
    def useTheValue(v: Int) = v + 64
}
```

But when storing my Foos in a mixed collection, it seems that my type parameter `T` always ends up being inferred up to `Any`.

```
val fooCollection:List[GenericFoo[_]] = List(DoubleFoo, IntFoo)

for {
    foo <- fooCollection
    defaultValue = foo.defaultValue
    result = foo.useTheValue(defaultValue)
    // Error: `defaultValue` has type `Any`, cannot call `useTheValue`

} yield result
```

Based on several answers to similar questions, I thought using type parameter wildcard (`GenericFoo[_]`), and maybe `ClassTag` would help keep type information, but I couldn't get this example to work as I wanted.

In the snippet above, I would want `foo.defaultValue` to be recognized as having the correct type (`T`) to be applicable in `foo.useTheValue()`. Have I missed something?

---

**Edit**: @gzm0 was prompt to suggest that I use abstract type members. My original use-case was a little more involved, as I am also defining an abstract type for a companion object. My actual code does something similar to:

```
trait GenericCompanion[T] {
    // Some "static" members
    def defaultValue: T
    def useTheValue(v: T): T
}

abstract class GenericFoo[T] {
    def getCompanion: GenericCompanion[T]

    // Because of this operation, it's important that we have the same type `T`
    def useCompanion: T = getCompanion.useTheValue(theActualValue)

    val theActualValue: T
}

object ConcreteCompanion[Double] extends GenericCompanion[Double] {
    // ...
}
object ConcreteFoo[Double] extends GenericFoo[Double] {
    def getCompanion = ConcreteCompanion
}
```

Each concrete implementation of `GenericFoo[T]` also comes with a `CompanionFoo[T]`. Concrete sub-classes of `GenericFoo` are supposed to instantiated, while `CompanionFoo[T]` objects are here to hold "static" properties and operations. In this context, it is very important that the type parameter in `GenericFoo` is the same as the type parameter in `GenericCompanion`.
(I hope this is clear enough, sorry if my example is convoluted!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a vanilla example for abstract type members. Try this:

```
abstract class GenericFoo {
    type V
    def defaultValue: V
    def useTheValue(v: V): V
}
object DoubleFoo extends GenericFoo {
    type V = Double
    def defaultValue = 42.0
    def useTheValue(v: Double) = v * 2
}
object IntFoo extends GenericFoo {
    type V = Int
    def defaultValue = 1337
    def useTheValue(v: Int) = v + 64
}

val fooCollection:List[GenericFoo] = List(DoubleFoo, IntFoo)
```

Rest of the code remains unchanged.

If you use an abstract type member (rather than a type parameter), Scala will take track of the concrete types it knows for a given value.

From your example explained:

```
val foo: GenericCollection = ???
val defaultValue = foo.defaultValue
// defaultValue: foo.V
foo.useTheValue(defaultValue)
// foo.useTheValue: (foo.V): foo.V
```

Although the compiler does not know what true type `foo.V` is, it can nevertheless figure out that the type signatures match and that using calling `useTheValue` with `defaultValue` is OK.

As far as I can tell, this would also be a perfectly OK reasoning with type parameters, Scala just does not do it.

**UPDATE**

You can still do this, even with the more involved example:

```
trait GenericCompanion {
    type T
    // Some "static" members
    def defaultValue: T
    def useTheValue(v: T): T
}

abstract class GenericFoo { self =>
    type T

    def getCompanion: GenericCompanion { type T = self.T }

    // Because of this operation, it's important that we have the same type `T`
    def useCompanion: T = getCompanion.useTheValue(theActualValue)

    val theActualValue: T
}
```

And the concrete implementations:

```
object ConcreteCompanionDouble extends GenericCompanion {
    type T = Double
    def defaultValue: Double = ???
    def useTheValue(v: Double): Double = ???
    // ...
}
object ConcreteFooDouble extends GenericFoo {
    type T = Double
    def getCompanion = ConcreteCompanionDouble
    val theActualValue: Double = ???
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am editing my question to explain why I think abstract type members won't apply in my case — but maybe I am wrong about that.

Comment: I did not know that it was possible to restrict the type with the syntax you demonstrated: `GenericCompanion { type T = self.T }`. This simplified my code greatly, thanks!